# How to set navigation page opened by default in jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We downloaded html template: https://codyhouse.co/gem/sliding-panels-template.

As for the full-page navigation, the `.cd-primary-nav` is placed below the `.cd-projects-container`. When the user clicks the `.cd-nav-trigger`, the `.slide-out` class is added to the project previews to reveal the navigation.

**We want change position of full page navigation, place it over cd-projects-container. In other words, we want to set navigation page opened by default.**

I have basic knowledge of css but I can not do what we want. Can anybody help and explain how it works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Ayaz, could you give an example of what you'd like to achieve? Maybe an image or a link.

Comment: Also, when you say 1) "change position of full page navigation...": what do you mean with `full page navigation`? The content of `.cd-primary-nav`?
And 2) "...place it over cd-projects-container": do you mean like a top navigation bar? Something like this  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp?

Comment: Hello @NicoDiz. No it is little bit different and difficult to explain. You can see demo in this link https://codyhouse.co/demo/sliding-panels-template/index.html
When you open this page first what you see is sliding panels. After clicking menu btn. panels slide up and open navigation page. I want only one thing. when you open or reload page should be displayed navigation page(not sliding panels). I hope I could explain. Thanks for your attention.
If you will need this is link of template for downloading.
https://github.com/bryanlimy/sliding-panels-template

Comment: So, you mean like navigation page is opened by default, right?

Comment: Yes , exactly :)  @NicoDiz

Comment: Hello @Ajaz, I just propose a change in the title and post an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1. Clone this repo   https://github.com/CodyHouse/sliding-panels-template   (this is the original template. The other repo you passed is different).
2. In the code, make this seven changes:

```
    // In style.css
    // at the end, that is line 788, add:
    .hide-in-default { opacity: 0; }


    // In index.html
    // Add class .nav-visible to `<a>` in line 16
    <a class="cd-nav-trigger cd-text-replace nav-visible" href="#primary-nav">Menu<span aria-hidden="true" class="cd-icon"></span></a>

    // Add class .hide-in-default to `<div>` in line 18:
    <div class="cd-projects-container hide-in-default">

    // replace line 134 with:
    <nav class="cd-primary-nav nav-visible nav-clickable" id="primary-nav">


    // In main.js
    // in line 29 add:
    removeHideInDefault();

    // in line 67 add:
    function removeHideInDefault() {
        try {
            var projectsContainer = document.querySelector('.cd-projects-container');
            var isHidden = projectsContainer && projectsContainer.classList.contains('hide-in-default');
            if (isHidden) projectsContainer.classList.remove('hide-in-default');
        } catch (reason) {
            console.error(reason);
        }
    }

    // finally, replace line 80 with:
    projectPreview.addClass('bg-loaded slide-out');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you select my answer as correct and upvote it? (Arrow up)